# Upper bound on the number of ismorphism classes of bilinear forms on $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms, geometry-of-numbers

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$A symmetric, positive definite bilinear form on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is any mapping $$b : \mathbb{Z}^n \times \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$$ satisfying

- $b$ is bilinear,
- $b(x,y) = b(y,x)$,
- $b(x,x) > 0$, whenever $x \neq 0$,
- for all $f \in \Hom(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathbb{Z})$ there exist unique elements $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ for which $f(x) = b(x,y_0)$ and $f(y) = b(x_0,y)$,

for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Two such bilinear forms $b, b'$ are *isomorphic*, given the existence of a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear isomorphism $\phi$ such that $b(\phi(x), \phi(y)) = b'(x,y)$. As usual "being isomorphic" is an equivalence relation.

A (famous?) theorem by Eisenstein and Hermite states that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes for each $n$.

> What are good upper bounds on the number of isomorphism classes of symmetric, positive definite bilinear forms on $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: A *lower* bound for this number is given by the Minkowski-Siegel formula,  see Serre's *Course in Arithmetic*, chap. V, 2.3, for an introduction. As Serre points out, the number of isomorphism classes of even lattices of rank 32 is more than $8.10^7$; it is unlikely that there is a "good" upper bound.

Comment: An upper bound can be obtained by multiplying the mass formula
by an upper bound on the number of automorphisms of the form.
That bound grows quickly with $n$, but not nearly as fast as
the mass formula, so the resulting upper bound should be
reasonably good (at least its logarithm will be of the right size).
For large $n$ it's probably true that most forms have automorphisms
only by $\{ \pm 1 \}$, which would mean that the mass-formula bound
is asymptotically sharp.  I don't know whether this has been proved,
or how hard it would be to prove it.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: A priori the question refers to all symmetric bilinear forms (not only to even ones)...